# Dropdown link won't display in block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with my mobile-dropdown menu for login and signup.
I have a function that adds class that hides all my links from header except first one (site name) and places a button that onClick shows them. But these links won't display in block, they are always inline no matter what I do and they push on child elements damaging whole design. Should i make separate div just for these two links? But then this div is out of sight. I really don't know what to do anymore.
This is my html:

```
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="brand" id="myTopnav">
          <a href="/#"><h1>{carrot}Plan your meal</h1></a>
   //this i want to hide  <a href="/#"><h3 className="login">Log In</h3></a>
   //this i want to hide  <a href="/#"><h3 className="signup">Sign Up</h3></a>
          <button className="icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>&#9776;</button>
        </div>
```

This is my function:

```
  handleClick() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "brand") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "brand";
    }
}
```

This is my @mobile css:

```
.brand a:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
.brand button {
  display: none;
}
.brand button.icon {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
.brand h3 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.brand h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
}
.brand.responsive {
  position: relative;
}
.brand.responsive button.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.brand.responsive a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.login {
  border: none;
}
```

Maybe I should rewrite all the links and make them ul?
Thank you in advance.

This is my GitHub Repo: https://github.com/Meret12/Planyourmeal
and project website (button shows below 767px) https://awcorp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `h3` inside your links are floating right, so they are out of the `HTML` flow so your `<a>` are displayed as `block` but with no content.

Just add:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.brand h3 {
    float:none;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped but I also added:
      position: relative;
      left: 370px;
so it is more on the right side just below the icon. I just want the site to resemble anything, i'll reconstruct it later anyways because i want to focus on React JS as soon as possible.